# ERROR TypeError: "this.authenticatedUser is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry, i'm french.. This is my problem:

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AuthOidcService, AuthUser } from '@cddng/auth-oidc-apim';
import { AuthService } from './service/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  appName: string;
  authenticatedUser: AuthUser;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private oidcAuth: AuthOidcService) {
    this.appName = environment.application_name;
    this.oidcAuth.init(environment.auth_oidc_config);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.oidcAuth.login();

    this.oidcAuth.oidcSecurityService.getIsAuthorized().subscribe((authorized: boolean) => {
      if (authorized) {
          this.authenticatedUser = this.oidcAuth.getAuthenticatedUserFromJwt();
      }
  });
  this.auth.idRh = this.authenticatedUser.idRh;
  this.auth.role = this.authenticatedUser.roles;
  console.log("*******************************************");
  console.log("idrh => " + this.auth.idRh);
  console.log("Roles => " + this.auth.role);
  console.log("isAdmin => " + this.auth.isAdmin);
  console.log("isExpert => " + this.auth.isExpert);
  console.log("isConsult => " + this.auth.isConsultation);
  console.log("*******************************************");

  }




  @HostListener('window:UserDisconnected') userDisconnected() {
    this.oidcAuth.corpHeaderLogout();
  }



}
```

And this error on console: 
`ERROR TypeError: "this.authenticatedUser is undefined"`

When i refresh the page, it's ok but not the first time

I think it's problem asynchron but i've not solution

Thank you for your answers

Comment: As indicated in the answer from Gerome, `subscribe` is asynchronous. You can read more here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#subscribe-in-heroescomponent

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the following lines inside the `subscribe` :

```
this.auth.idRh = this.authenticatedUser.idRh;
this.auth.role = this.authenticatedUser.roles;
```

As the subscription is asynchronous, you need to wait for the returned value before you can use it.