# Angular: Object possibly null after subscribing to it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, subscribe

loadUserInfo() is returning an Observable of type UserModel. I want this.user to be accessible in other functions as well. Right now if I try to access it outside of the subscription it says that it is null. Same with trying to access it in the HTML

```
  ngOnInit(){
     this.subscriptions.add(this.loadUserInfo().subscribe((user: UserModel) => {
           this.user = user;
      }));
  }
  someOtherFunc(){
     console.log(this.user) //Does not work here
  }
```

Comment: That will be because `someOtherFunc` is called before the observable has returned a value. Can you show more code to demonstrate the problem, and create a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Observable/subscribe operation is asynchronous, you can only access `this.user` only after the async operation is completed. I have added the `this.someOtherFunc()` function call in the code below.

```
 ngOnInit(){
     this.subscriptions.add(this.loadUserInfo().subscribe((user: UserModel) => {
           this.user = user;
           this.someOtherFunc(); // call function here
      }));
  }
  someOtherFunc(){
     console.log(this.user) 
  }
```

Please see this section of the webpage: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#observable-heroservice. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61754447/3389828